# I have to reset the admin password each time

Tags: password, reset

IDK why, but i have to reset the admin password everytime im trying to login.

The password is correctly setted in the DB, but i have to reset it each time.

Please give me some help, advise, or guide with this problem.

Comment: is this a technical/programming/development question? This looks like a user support issue, have you tried asking this on the .org support forums?

Comment: Im not even sure, cause the installation is relatively new, and its up to date. So im going to try .org if you think thats better.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have default settings set in your browser? What browser are you using?? It sounds like you might have cookies or Javascript disabled or something else set wrong on the client side.